# The size of the train_data (1) couldn't be smaller than batch_size (32)

Tags: python, tensorflow, tensorflow-lite

my structure asset to training (tflite)

```
!ls  /root/.keras/datasets/model_test/
!ls  /root/.keras/datasets/model_test/abrasive/
```

```
abrasive  adhesive
'abrasive (1).jpg'  'abrasive (2).jpg'  'abrasive (3).jpg'
```

init ImageClassifierDataLoader

```
data = ImageClassifierDataLoader.from_folder(image_path)
train_data, test_data = data.split(0.3)
```

```
INFO:tensorflow:Load image with size: 6, num_label: 2, labels: abrasive, adhesive.
INFO:tensorflow:Load image with size: 6, num_label: 2, labels: abrasive, adhesive.
```

when i try to customize model with

```
model = image_classifier.create(train_data)
```

i got

```
ValueError: The size of the train_data (1) couldn't be smaller than batch_size (32). To solve this problem, set the batch_size smaller or increase the size of the train_data.
```

what does that mean? the data test must be > 32 ??
where is batch_size ?

I found the same thing, but quite different and I didn't get it (not simple ) [Increasing batch_size of dataset for Pytorch neural network](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58681854/increasing-batch-size-of-dataset-for-pytorch-neural-network)

Answer (score 0):

Don't use batch size as batch size is used when the dataset is very large and you want to train your data by splitting it into batches to improve the training process

Answer (score 0):

When you create your model, the `create()` function offers the possibility to define `batch_size` (default is 32). To reuse your example, you may write:

```
model = image_classifier.create(train_data, batch_size=1)
```

See also [Change the training hyperparameters](https://www.tensorflow.org/lite/tutorials/model_maker_image_classification#change_the_training_hyperparameters)